# Actionscript3; make a dynamic text box show text while hovered

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, mouseover, dynamic-text

I'm trying to create one of my first actionscript3s...I want to make a dynamic text box (dynText) write a description of what the hovered button (stopButton) does.

No text is shown when I hover the button and I get no error message. Why?

This is my code

```
dynText.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myInfoHandler )
function myInfoHandler( event ){
    if(event.target.name == "stopButton"){
    dynText.text = "Stop animation!";
    }
}
```

And just to make sure it isn't the text fields fault: to make a dynamic text field do I just create a text field and choose "Dynamic text" in the dropodown?

I've tried too google and read other answers but I guess I'm too much of a noob to understand...

Comment: have you tried dynText.buttonMode = true; dynText.mouseChildren = false;

Comment: Have you added your textfield as a child? Like `addChild(dynText);`. May be you do not see it because it is not added.

Comment: No I haven't tried any of that. Where should I put it? Before the rest of the code or...?

Comment: @Jari tried putting addChild(dynText); before the rest of the code but it makes no difference.

Comment: @The_asMan I don't get where to put the code you recommended?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have a stop button and want to show a text (like a tooltip) when that is hovered. If so, you should add the event listener to the button, not to the text box. So like stopButton(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myInfoHandler) instead of dynText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myInfoHandler).

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö YES! It works! Tack så hemskt mycket! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line:

```
dynText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myInfoHandler);
```

to this:

```
stopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myInfoHandler);
```

You want the listener to trigger when the button is moused over, not the text field, so you need to add the listener to the button itself.